# Как вывести поля объекта который находится в массиве?

Tags: php, yii2

у меня есть массив в котором n-е количество объектов.
Вот var_damp:

```
array(5) { [1]=> NULL [2]=> object(app\models\Lot)#139 (10) { ["_attributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> array(16) { ["id"]=> int(28) ["name"]=> string(13) "MF ładowarka" ["imgsrc"]=> string(28) "/uploads/rola_1532427040.jpg" ["description"]=> string(42) "łądowarka MF, silnik perkins, do porawek" ["start_price"]=> int(0) ["current_price"]=> int(10250) ["max_bid_user"]=> int(32500) ["max_bid_user2"]=> int(10000) ["id_user_max"]=> int(10) ["id_user_max2"]=> int(8) ["time"]=> string(19) "2018-07-28 13:02:00" ["id_auctions"]=> int(6) ["status"]=> int(1) ["deposit"]=> int(1000) ["ofert"]=> int(113) ["oferenci"]=> int(3) } ["_oldAttributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> array(16) { ["id"]=> int(28) ["name"]=> string(13) "MF ładowarka" ["imgsrc"]=> string(28) "/uploads/rola_1532427040.jpg" ["description"]=> string(42) "łądowarka MF, silnik perkins, do porawek" ["start_price"]=> int(0) ["current_price"]=> int(10250) ["max_bid_user"]=> int(32500) ["max_bid_user2"]=> int(10000) ["id_user_max"]=> int(10) ["id_user_max2"]=> int(8) ["time"]=> string(19) "2018-07-28 13:02:00" ["id_auctions"]=> int(6) ["status"]=> int(1) ["deposit"]=> int(1000) ["ofert"]=> int(113) ["oferenci"]=> int(3) } ["_related":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> array(0) { } ["_relationsDependencies":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> array(0) { } ["_errors":"yii\base\Model":private]=> NULL ["_validators":"yii\base\Model":private]=> NULL ["_scenario":"yii\base\Model":private]=> string(7) "default" ["_events":"yii\base\Component":private]=> array(0) { } ["_eventWildcards":"yii\base\Component":private]=> array(0) { } ["_behaviors":"yii\base\Component":private]=> array(0) { } } [3]=> object(app\models\Lot)#158 (10) { ["_attributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> array(16) { ["id"]=> int(11) ["name"]=> string(11) "Testing Lot" ["imgsrc"]=> string(28) "/uploads/rola_1531470850.jpg" ["description"]=> string(224) "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus ea placeat repellat praesentium similique repudiandae eos, quibusdam, vel sit iusto quia velit voluptas provident harum magni nisi suscipit tempora officiis." ["start_price"]=> int(0) ["current_price"]=> int(550) ["max_bid_user"]=> int(700) ["max_bid_user2"]=> int(500) ["id_user_max"]=> int(2) ["id_user_max2"]=> int(10) ["time"]=> string(16) "2018-07-30 17:01" ["id_auctions"]=> int(5) ["status"]=> int(1) ["deposit"]=> int(1000) ["ofert"]=> int(0) ["oferenci"]=> int(3) } ["_oldAttributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> array(16) { ["id"]=> int(11) ["name"]=> string(11) "Testing Lot" ["imgsrc"]=> string(28) "/uploads/rola_1531470850.jpg" ["description"]=> string(224) "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus ea placeat repellat praesentium similique repudiandae eos, quibusdam, vel sit iusto quia velit voluptas provident harum magni nisi suscipit tempora officiis." ["start_price"]=> int(0) ["current_price"]=> int(550) ["max_bid_user"]=> int(700) ["max_bid_user2"]=> int(500) ["id_user_max"]=> int(2) ["id_user_max2"]=> int(10) ["time"]=> string(16) "2018-07-30 17:01" ["id_auctions"]=> int(5) ["status"]=> int(1) ["deposit"]=> int(1000) ["ofert"]=> int(0)
```

Вывожу на страницу так:

```
<?php foreach ($alllot as $item){ ?>
                    <div>
                        <table>
                          <tr>
                            <th rowspan="2"><div style="width: 80px;height: 80px;"><img style="width: 100%;" src="<?=$item->imgsrc?>"></div></th>
                            <th class="p_th">Nazwa</th>
                            <th class="p_th">Aktualna cena</th>
                            <th class="p_th">Twoja maksymalna oferta</th>
                            <th class="p_th">Czas zakończenia</th>
                            <th  rowspan="2"><a  href="<?= yii\helpers\Url::to(['site/singllot','id'=>$item->id])?>">View Lot</a></th>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="p_td"><?=$item->name?></td>
                            <td class="p_td"><?=$item->current_price?></td>
                            <td class="p_td"><?=$item->max_bid_user?></td>
                            <td class="p_td"><p class="p_time_a" id="getting-started<?=$item->id?>"></p></td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

Получаю ошибку Trying to get property of non-object, понимаю, что не могу достучатся до объекта, делал с двумя foreach, не увенчалось успехами, возможно не правильно, что то описал при двух foreach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первый же елемент массива - null. А он действительно "non-object".

Добавьте проверку в первой строке Вашего примера:

```
<?php foreach ($alllot as $item){ if($item === null) continue; ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!